# Show that if $P(0 \leq X \leq c)=1$ then $Var(X) \leq \frac{c^2}{4}$

Tags: probability

I need to show that if $$P(0 \leq X \leq c)=1$$ then $$Var(X) \leq \frac{c^2}{4}$$

I can show that using 2 things:
First, that $E[X^2] \leq cE[X]$
and secondly that $Var(X) \leq c^2[\alpha(1-\alpha)]$ for $\alpha=\frac{E[X]}{c}$.

Could anyone help me prove these 2 steps?

Last step is quite immediate.

Comment: What does $a$ mean in $Var(X) \leq c^2[\alpha (a - \alpha)]$ pls?

Comment: I am terribly sorry. It should be 1. Edited original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Proof

Define a new random variable $Y = X - \frac{c}{2}$. It is easy to know that 
$$
Var(Y) = Var(X)
$$
by using the fact $Var(X+a)=Var(X)$. Thus we only need to show $$Var(Y) \leq \frac{c^2}{4}$$

Since $0 \leq X \leq c$, we have
$$
-\frac{c}{2} \leq Y \leq \frac{c}{2}
$$
thus
$$
E[Y^2] \leq \frac{c^2}{4}
$$

Therefore,
$$
Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - (E[Y])^2 \leq \frac{c^2}{4} - (E[Y])^2 \leq \frac{c^2}{4}
$$

---

### Another Proof

- We first prove that
  $E[X^2] \leq cE[X]
  $. This is easy since $E[X^2] \leq E[cX] = cE[X]$.
- We next prove that $Var(X) \leq \frac{c^2}{4}$. Note that
  $$
  Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 \leq c(E[X] - \frac{E[X]^2}{c}) \tag{1}
  $$
  Moreover,
  \begin{align}
  &(2E[X] - c)^2 \\
  =\ &4E[x]^2 - 4cE[x] + c^2 \\
  =\ &4c(\frac{E[X]^2}{c} - E[x] + \frac{c}{4}) \\
  \geq\ &0 
  \end{align}
  thus, we have
  $$
  E[X] - \frac{E[X]^2}{c} \leq \frac{c}{4} \tag{2}
  $$

According to (1) and (2), it is proved.

Comment: That's great but I need some approach for those 2 steps I wrote down at the question.

Comment: @UdiBehar I see. Let me try.

Comment: @UdiBehar Is the new proof you want?

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a lot.